# Ender 3 Pro bed is lower in the middle

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, bed-leveling, calibration, glass-bed

I just purchased this Ender 3 Pro about 1 week ago and since then I've been having nightmares with leveling/tramming the printer bed. From having to tram it again after every print to not being able to level it at all.
Since then I've been reading and watching a lot of problem-related content to try and find a solution.

The two most recommended upgrades were a glass bed and stiffer springs for the bed so that's what I bought. I purchased the original Creality glass bed and the yellow springs and for a day or so I got it to work in an acceptable way but I still had to tram the bed every couple of prints.
Today for some unknown reason, I woke up and I can't seem to get my bed leveled in the middle. I've tried every possible solution that crossed my mind but the middle of the bed is still too far from the nozzle and the filament won't stick.

Comment: The recommended purchase is an auto bed leveling probe.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your bed is deformed, I have this problem too. The easiest way to test it is to get a metal ruler and put it on its side vertically on the glass bed (at a 45° angle). If you see any light seeping through the middle, then the bed is sagging, but if you see light on the edges, then the bed has a bump. The easiest and cheapest way to fix this is to put post-its (you can use one or more) under the mat on the locations where you see the light.

Answer (score 0):

Glass beds are rigid, they won't sag in the middle after a few days, or months, or years. So the problem might be the undercarriage levelling equipment.

The screws may be unwinding or slipping somehow. I suggest you level it one by one and fix the knobs so they cannot turn and then try it out. Perhaps before that unwind the knobs fully and examine the threads for problems like slippage.

Comment: the glass might also be deformed, or  it is actually the print deforming as it cools.

Comment: @Trish glass was fine but deformed overnight? Seems unlikely, as does the print deforming since it never gets a chance to cool. It's failing on first layer

Comment: unlikely, but glass under stress can bend very slightly.

Comment: @Trish never seen it when it's on a flat surface so I just gave the most likely scenario for the OP

Comment: I suspected that the screws where slipping too that's why I bought the yellow kit of springs that are stiffer and it made it not really easy for them to move only by the printer vibration.

For the glass bed possible deforming I also added some foil pieces on the center of my printer bed under the glass.

I changed some settings on my slicer to make it easy to print and I'm getting some prints out of it again but the middle of the bed is still lower than the rest of it!

Comment: Change the glass then. I don't have a fancy glass bed, just a piece I cut from a broken louvre at first, PETG ruined that eventually so I'm now using glass cut from an old window